# Android : Set Notification Text & Title Color?

Tags: android, notifications

I am show a download notification to indicate the download percentage i want to set the title and text color to match the android version text color.
if i set the color text to black the text would not show in android 4.0.3 if i set it to white its would not show in 2.2.1.

any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use resource for the style definitions, and create different versions for the core releases of Android, and put the resources into different folders for each platform you need different styling for. More details here:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html

Comment: there is anther way to handle this issue via system color.
and 
how can i make the download notification like Market notification in download progress.